# Sites blocked in /etc/hosts often doesn't work

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, firefox, hosts

I'm using a Macbook Pro as a productivity/work machine and have Facebook and reddit blocked with `/etc/hosts`:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
0.0.0.0         facebook.com
::0             facebook.com
0.0.0.0         reddit.com
::0             reddit.com
```

This has worked for a while in all browsers, but recently stopped working in Firefox and Safari, and I can't figure out why. I was previously using 127.0.0.1, but when that stopped working I tried 0.0.0.0 instead, no dice.

I did install Avast just recently so I thought that could have been the problem, what with its web security features, but I uninstalled the browser add-on in Safari and Firefox and I was still able to access Facebook and reddit just fine.

And I just tried uninstalling the add-ons again, and restarted the computer. Now, Google Chrome can access Facebook, but not reddit. Firefox can't access either, and Safari can access both...

I'm using OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: You could post your answer below and accept it. That would help others a) who may face similar issues, b) avoid answering this question.

Comment: This site definitively works better if you post answers as answers and do not include them into the question. I've edited your question accordingly, please add the answer below yourself.

Comment: I wasn't allowed to post an answer since my account was too new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem. It seems I need to block both the domain website.com and the address www.website.com. I didn't know that was necessary. I edited them in there and now the blocking is consistently working everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

The following site clearly explains how to block a site step by step using hosts on etc by means of terminal: 
[wikiHow-Block a Website on Mac](http://www.wikihow.com/Block-a-Website-on-Mac)

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.